# iPhone locked when calling with headphones

Tags: iphone, headphones, screen-lock

When calling I use my iPhone 5S with headphones on and it always gets locked during the call. This doesnt happen when calling phone to ear. Is there a way how to prevent iPhone to lock when having a call with headphones?

Answer (score 1):

When you're on a call whilst wearing earphones the iPhone is designed to AutoLock, this happens with all iPhones not just yours.

You can disable that feature from Settings➜Display&Brightness and set it to never.

[image]

Comment: note that this setting is a global setting meaning that this obviously will also disable auto lock in every other app. :)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I meant. I definitely want to keep using auto-lock for all other reasons, I just dont want the phone to be auto-locked during the active call.

Comment: You're asking for something that doesn't exist mate